# How to simulate a hanging filesystem?

Tags: linux, nfs

I'd like to verify an application's behavior when trying to read from a bad filesystem (most notably: a hung NFS mount where reads might just hang forever if left unchecked).

Is there an easy way to locally reproduce this behavior? Be great if I could just force-mount something that doesn't exist, or mount a local ram disk and corrupt it, or lock it from reads such that it hangs rather than erroring out, or something of the sort. It should be something I could do reproducibly as part of a small integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a directory to export: `mkdir /tmp/nfs`
2. configure the directory, by adding the line `/tmp/nfs *(sync,sync,ro,no_subtree_check,fsid=0468884e-fdab-11e9-8ee6-4b007bc13e45)` to `/etc/exports`
3. `sudo exportfs -ra`
4. make sure the NFS server is running.
5. create the directory for the client to mount: `mkdir /tmp/hang`
6. `mount -t nfs -o vers=3 localhost:/tmp/nfs /tmp/hang`
7. run `ls /tmp/hang` - everything is fine.
8. shut down the NFS server.
9. run `ls /tmp/hang` - it will hang.
10. run the NFS server again.
11. the `ls` command will release.

An alternative to shutting down the NFS server is to block the client via `iptables`. This has the advantage that you can set up multiple network interfaces, mount multiple clients via different interfaces, and then selectively block clients by blocking network interfaces with `iptables`.

Comment: Thanks! This works at the moment. The one downside is, it's a system-wide state change, so I wouldn't be able to run one test that just times out, and another where the system recovers, simultaneously, but I suspect that's the best we can do without doing something like writing a custom FUSE adapter (maybe there is one in open source land we can use already...)

Comment: I suppose you can just use something like https://github.com/skorokithakis/python-fuse-sample/blob/master/passthrough.py with few `sleep` around.